# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Tags: python, python-2.7, split, attributeerror

Using `Python 2.7.3.1`

I don't understand what the problem is with my coding! I get this error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split`

This is my code:

```
myList = ['hello']

myList.split()
```

Comment: myList = ['hello']
myList.split()

Comment: what language are you writing this in? What is the goal of your code?

Comment: It is python 2.7.3.1

Comment: please tag it as such and update the question

Comment: no need to apologize! don't be afraid to ask questions and contribute. just always try to provide as much detail as possible to help those that help you!

Comment: Lists do not have a `.split()` method. What are you attempting to achieve?

Comment: I want the list myList = 'hello' to become myList = ['h','e','l','l','o']

Comment: `myList = list(myList)`

Answer (score 6):

You can simply do `list(myList[0])` as below:

```
>>> myList = ['hello']
>>> myList=list(myList[0])
>>> myList
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

See [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#list) here

Comment: Is there a way to acheive that in one line? mylist = [list('hello)[0])  just returns 'h' as in slicing. Actually Yes. alpha = [c for c in list(string.ascii_lowercase)]

Answer (score 2):

To achieve what you are looking for:

```
myList = ['hello']
result = [c for c in myList[0]] # a list comprehension

>>> print result
 ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

More info on list comprehensions: http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Lists in python do not have a split method. split is a method of strings(`str.split()`)

**Example:**

```
>>> s = "Hello, please split me"
>>> print s.split()
['Hello,', 'please', 'split', 'me']
```

By default, split splits on whitespace.

Check out more info: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm: