# list() function confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I don't understand how the `list` function works.

Here is the research I have done:

Documentation I am looking at:

[documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-list)

In particular, I am looking at this paragraph:

> class list([iterable]) Return a list whose items are the same and in
>   the same order as iterable’s items. iterable may be either a sequence,
>   a container that supports iteration, or an iterator object. If
>   iterable is already a list, a copy is made and returned, similar to
>   iterable[:]. For instance, list('abc') returns ['a', 'b', 'c'] and
>   list( (1, 2, 3) ) returns [1, 2, 3]. If no argument is given, returns
>   a new empty list, [].
>
> list is a mutable sequence type, as documented in Sequence Types —
>   str, unicode, list, tuple, bytearray, buffer, xrange. For other
>   containers see the built in dict, set, and tuple classes, and the
>   collections module.

Here is another post:

[Another post about the list function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26942061/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-split/26942345)

On that post, the someone posts the following:

```
>>> myList = ['hello']
>>> myList=list(myList[0])
>>> myList
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

But when I do this:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
     path_files.append(files)

path_files
[['combinedPdfs.py', 'meetingminutes.pdf', 'meetingminutes_encrypted.pdf', 'pdf_intro.py', 'pdf_paranoia.py', 'readDocx.py']]

>>> path_files_2 = list(path_files[0])
>>> path_files_2
['combinedPdfs.py', 'meetingminutes.pdf', 'meetingminutes_encrypted.pdf', 'pdf_intro.py', 'pdf_paranoia.py', 'readDocx.py']
>>> path_files_2[0]
'combinedPdfs.py'
>>> path_files_2[1]
'meetingminutes.pdf'
```

Why did what I do work differently than the user from the other post?

**Edit #1:**

If I run something like this:

```
>>> myList2 = ['hello', 'goodbye']
>>> myList2[0]
'hello'
>>> myList2 = list(myList2)
>>> myList2
['hello', 'goodbye']
>>> myList2  = list(myList2[0])
>>> myList2
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

If I run something like this:

```
>>> myList4 = [['Hello', 'goodbye']]
>>> myList4 = list(myList4)
>>> myList4
[['Hello', 'goodbye']]
>>> myList4 = list(myList4[0])
>>> myList4
['Hello', 'goodbye']
```

I see the definition, but I wish there was a more "laymans" way to explain it.

Comment: Notice that in your case, the first (and single) element of `path_files` is another list (see the `[[...]]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your list called `path_files`, this list is actually a list within a list. You can see this because of the double square brackets on the end of your list, e.g. `[['combinedPdfs.py', ..., 'readDocx.py']]`. A single list would have only one set of square brackets.

The command `>>> path_files = list(path_files)[0]`, essentially, returns the first item in the list broken out as a list. So, in the case of the `['hello']` list, it broke out `hello` into separate characters. With your list, it broke out the first item in the list (in this case, another list) and broke it out into its own list.

While I cannot see where you defined `path_files_2` (I am assuming it is the same as the new `path_files`), when you type `path_files_2[0]` you are saying to return the first item in the list (zero-indexed).

I generally don't think of it as "the list function" but rather "the list datatype" that has its own methods. When you type `list(...)`, I don't think of it as a "function" but rather as a method of data type casting one datatype into a list datatype.

Comment: path_files_2 = [] is how I defined it, sorry about that.

Comment: Anyhow, thank you for the post, sadly it got closed, but I marked this as the answer.

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you.